# Seq2Seq model learns to only output EOS token (<\s>) after a few iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

I am creating a chatbot trained on [Cornell Movie Dialogs Corpus](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html) using [NMT](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt).

I am basing my code in part from https://github.com/bshao001/ChatLearner and https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/tree/master/assignments/chatbot

During training, I print a random output answer fed to the decoder from the batch and the corresponding answer that my model predicts to observe the learning progress.

**My issue:** After only about 4 iterations of training, the model learns to output the EOS token (`<\s>`) for every timestep. It always outputs that as its response (determined using argmax of logits) even as training continues. Once in a while, rarely, the model outputs series of periods as its answer.

I also print the top 10 logit values during training (not just the argmax) to see if maybe the correct word is somewhere in there, but it seems to be predicting the most common words in the vocab (e.g i, you, ?, .). Even these top 10 words don't change much during training.

I have made sure to correctly count input sequence lengths for encoder and decoder, and added SOS (`<s>`) and EOS (also used for padding) tokens accordingly. I also perform **masking** in the loss calculation.

Here is a sample output:

**Training iteration 1:**

```
Decoder Input: <s> sure . sure . <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> 
<\s> <\s>
Predicted Answer: wildlife bakery mentality mentality administration 
administration winston winston winston magazines magazines magazines 
magazines
```

...

**Training iteration 4:**

```
Decoder Input: <s> i guess i had it coming . let us call it settled . 
<\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s>
Predicted Answer: <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> 
<\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s> <\s>
```

After a few more iterations, it settles on only predicting EOS (and rarely some periods)

I am not sure what could be causing this issue and have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I let it train for over a hundred thousand iterations and it still only outputs EOS (and occasional periods). The training loss also does not decrease after a few iteration (it remains at around 47 from the beginning)

Comment: What constitutes an "iteration"? Is it a minibatch? An epoch? Either way, this behaviour does not surprise me that much. When I train RNNs they usually go through a phase, early on during training, where they repeatedly output the same symbol. The solution may simply be that you need to train the model for longer. If the behaviour persists after training for many epochs then something may be wrong.

Comment: An iteration in this case is just applying gradient descent to a single random batch. I have let it train for a a few thousand iterations and the predicted output is always EOS. Even when I inspect the top 10 logits as training progresses (not just the max used for prediction output), it seems to always be the highest frequency (most common) words in the vocab that have highest logits. I am not sure what could be causing this problem as I based my code off the [NMT tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt)

Comment: @myrtlecat Update: I let it train for over a hundred thousand iterations and it still only outputs EOS (and occasional periods). The training loss also does not decrease after the first iteration (it remains at around 47)

Comment: Noel, Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue, and I followed the advice from @myrtlecat too. My model gets around 98% accuracy and then drops down to 5% accuracy and then climbs back up to 20%, but it still is only predicting end tokens. I have no idea why the accuracy is even changing when it only outputs the argmax which is always the end token

Answer (score 0):

recently I also work on seq2seq model.
I have encountered your problem before, in my case, I solve it by changing the loss function.

You said you use mask, so I guess you use `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` as I did.

I changed to `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, and it works normally (and higher computation cost).

(Edit 05/10/2018. Pardon me, I need to edit since I found there is an egregious mistake in my code)

`tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` can work really well, if the shape of `logits`  ,`targets` , `mask` are right. 
As defined in official document :
[tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss)

```
loss=tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits=decoder_logits,
                                      targets=decoder_targets,
                                      weights=masks) 

#logits:  [batch_size, sequence_length, num_decoder_symbols]  
#targets: [batch_size, sequence_length] 
#weights: [batch_size, sequence_length]
```

Well, it can still work even if the shape are not meet. But the result could be weird (lots of #EOS  #PAD... etc).

Since the `decoder_outputs`, and the `decoder_targets` might have the same shape as required ( In my case, my `decoder_targets` has the shape `[sequence_length, batch_size]` ).
So try to use `tf.transpose` to help you reshape the tensor.

Comment: i'm facing the exactly same problem , does anyone know how to solve this?
Is the sequences loss logits need to be softmaxed?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's due to the optimizer, where I mistakenly set a large lr_decay so that it does not work normally anymore.

Check Lr and Optimizer / Scheduler may help.